# Converting .txt file to CSV

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I need code that can read a .txt file and output the data inside into a CSV file. The .txt file would have data in this form:

```
Jeff/Terry/01-10-2020/1-2
+Tom/02-10-2020
-Jeff/03-10-2020
```

And I need to write the data into a CSV file where the string is split and separated every time it encounters a "/". So the CSV file would look something like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jeff | Terry | 01-10-2020 | 1-2 |
| +Tom | 02-10-2020 |  |  |
| -Jeff | 03-10-2020 |  |  |

Furthermore I would also need code to write this CSV file data back into another .txt file in the same format, with the "/" separating the data of the cells.

I currently have this:

```
import csv
with open ("data.txt", "r") as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (line.split("/") for line in stripped if line
    open ("data.csv", "w") as out_file:
             writer = csv.writer(out_file)
             writer.writerow(('first', 'second'))
             writer.writerows(lines)
```

Currently it is nowhere near the functionality that I need, and it is also giving me syntax errors on the "o" of open on the 4th last line, `open ("data.csv", "w") as out_file:`.

Comment: You're missing an end paren on line 3

Comment: The csv module allows you to specify the separator. So this is pretty straight forward, no need to do the splits.

Comment: You need to say `with open` if you're saying `as out_file`

Comment: @thebjorn now the "a" in the `open ("data.csv", "w") as out_file:` "as" is being highlighted
@PeterWood could you explain? I assume there is a far shorter way of writing out what I had written using the CSV module

Answer (score 1):

There are a few grammatical errors here.

- Line 4 has missing closing parenthesis: `lines = (line.split("/") for line in stripped if line)`.
- Line 5 should start with `with`: `with open("data.csv", "w") as out_file:`.
- Also, it's better to place the 5th line outside the `with` block on line 2.
- Lines 6 through 8 should have one indent, not two.

Try the following (see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)):

```
import csv
with open("data.txt", "r", newline='') as in_file:
    lines = list(csv.reader(in_file, delimiter="/"))
with open("data.csv", "w", newline='') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter="/")
    writer.writerow(('first', 'second'))
    writer.writerows(lines)
```